# List with circles and rectangles

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I try to implement the following list known from Word (SmartArt).

[image: List with circles and rectangles]

The lines can be straight.

Currently this is my solution:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left; text-align: center; width: 55px;">
        <hr width="2" size="20" class="hrInhouse">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div>
    <div style="float: left;"class="circleInhouse"></div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 80%;">
        <p class="boxInhouse">
            Strategischer Verkauf &#x3c;<a href="strategischerVerkauf.php">Seminarthemen</a>&#x3e;
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div>
    <div style="float: left; text-align: center; width: 55px;">
        <hr width="2" size="20" class="hrInhouse">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div>
    <div style="float: left;"class="circleInhouse"></div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 80%;">
        <p class="boxInhouse">
            Prozessorientierte Verkaufstechnik &#x3c;<a href="prozessorientierteVerkaufstechnik.php">Seminarthemen</a>&#x3e;
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div style="float: left; text-align: center; width: 55px;">
        <hr width="2" size="20" class="hrInhouse">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div>
    <div style="float: left;"class="circleInhouse"></div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 80%;">
        <p class="boxInhouse">
            Team-Selling &#x3c;<a href="teamSelling.php">Seminarthemen</a>&#x3e;
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div>
    <div style="float: left; text-align: center; width: 55px;">
        <hr width="2" size="20" class="hrInhouse">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
    background: #415985;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px; 
    font-size: 12px;   

}

.circle{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #415985;
}

.hr{
    padding: 0; 
    margin-bottom: 0; 
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Inline CSS will be outsourced to the CSS file.

However I'm not fully satisfied as the lines don't fit exactly to the circles and the boxes/rectangles have to be moved "behind" the circles.

How can this be done? I'm looking for a clean solution.

Comment: "Inline CSS will be outsourced to the CSS file."...if you did that **now** it might make it easier for SO users to adapt. Perhaps a proper JSFiddle demo with the extracted CSS?

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `li`'s and `pseudo-elements` to do this

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
  }
li{
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  height:70px;
  padding:20px;
  padding-left:80px;
  font-size:28px;
  color:#fff;
  background:dodgerblue;
  margin:10px 0;
  position:relative;
  }
li:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:#fff;
  border:5px solid dodgerblue;
  border-radius:50%;
  top:0px;
  left:-50px;
  }
ul:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:5px;
  height:500px;
  background:#fff;
  border:2px solid dodgerblue;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
 </ul>
```

This one has a bit more curved lines like you asked

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
  }
li{
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  height:70px;
  padding:20px;
  padding-left:80px;
  font-size:28px;
  color:#fff;
  background:dodgerblue;
  margin:10px 0;
  position:relative;
  }
li:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:#fff;
  border:5px solid dodgerblue;
  border-radius:50%;
  top:0px;
  left:-50px;
  }
ul:before{
  content:"";
  left:-30px;
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  height:550px;
  background:#fff;
  border-right:5px double dodgerblue;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: A radial gradient background (with modified position) for the container `ul` element might be able to produce the circular connector also (untested) :)

Answer (score 2):

To build on @Akshay's answer, you could also then modify each `li` if you know how many you are going to have.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px;
}
ul::before {
  content: '';
  width: 350px;
  height: 550px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 8px double #0195cb;
  border-left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: -200px;
}
li {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
  background: dodgerblue;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
}
li:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 5px solid dodgerblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0px;
  left: -50px;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: 90px;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Image map if you want it to look exactly like the picture.

[**DEMO**](https://arcx.s3.amazonaws.com/flexCircle.html)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>flexCircle</title>
<style>
area { cursor:pointer; pointer-events:auto; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<section>
<nav>
<img src="flexCircle.png" alt="" usemap="#fcMap" />
<map name="fcMap" id="fcMap">
    <area alt="circleLink" title="Back" href="#" shape="circle" coords="75,64,45" />
    <area alt="circleLink" title="Home" href="#" shape="circle" coords="101,171,45" />
    <area alt="circleLink" title="Forward" href="#" shape="circle" coords="75,282,45" />
    <area alt="bannerLink" title="About" href="#" shape="poly" coords="109,244,633,243,633,314,110,314,121,281" />
    <area alt="bannerLink" title="Blog" href="#" shape="poly" coords="137,137,633,138,633,205,135,208,151,174" />
    <area alt="bannerLink" title="Contact" href="#" shape="poly" coords="111,30,634,25,632,100,108,97,124,63" />
</map>
<!-- Coordinates generated with Easy Imagemap Generator by Dario D. Miller | http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/ -->
</nav>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```